# datatables number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do i get the number of columns in a datatable?

I can get the number of rows by doing oTable.fnGetData().length but how do I get the number of columns so I can Iterate over each cell like this:

```
var numColumns = //How to get the number of columns?
    for(var r=0;r<oTable.fnGetData().length;r++){
        for(var c=0;c <= numColumns;c++){
            console.log("[R]: "+r+ "[C]: "+c+ " data: "+oTable.fnGetData(r,c));   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fnGetData can be used to get a single data row.
So, you can simply check the length of the data row for the number of columns.

Example:

```
oTable.fnGetData(someRowNumber).length;
```

The above will return the number of columns in that data row.

Comment: makes sense :). After I read the API documentation I noticed that if you give a parameter you get an array, instead of an object... if no values are passed you get an object, and if two parameter are passed you get a string... (-1 because it's index 0). thanks!

Comment: what happens if the datatable is empty?

Comment: This code will not produce correct answers all the time as the number of data fields doesn't always equal to number of columns. Also it will return `undefined` if source data is array of objects.

Answer (score 21):

#### GET NUMBER OF COLUMNS

- **DataTables 1.9+**

  ```js
  // Get number of all columns
  var numCols = $('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().aoColumns.length;

  // Get number of visible columns
  var numCols = $('#example thead th').length;
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL647oLr/4/) for demonstration.
- **DataTables 1.10+**

  ```js
  // Get number of all columns
  var numCols = $('#example').DataTable().columns().nodes().length;

  // Get number of visible columns
  var numCols = $('#example').DataTable().columns(':visible').nodes().length;

  // Get number of visible columns (alternative way)
  var numCols = $('#example thead th').length;
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpskjkf4/3/) for demonstration.

#### ITERATE OVER EACH CELL

- **DataTables 1.10.6+**

  ```js
  $('#example').DataTable().cells().every( function (rowIndex, colIndex) {
      var data = this.data();

      console.log("Row:", rowIndex, "Col:", colIndex, "Data:", data);
  });
  ```

Comment: How to get all visible datatable columns index in an array?